# Symfony 1.4 not showing php errors

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm having some troubles with symfony 1.4. When a 500 error happens all I get is a blank screen.
Parse errors are showing correctly but not in the "symfony-style" screen with the stack trace.

On my index_dev.php file I have debug enabled like this:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('store', 'dev', true);
```

Also I have this configuration in the settings.yml file in the apps/store directory:

```
dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
```

Any ideas of what is going on?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check error log?

Comment: Symfony logs are working fine but they doesn't show errors don't know why.

Comment: Make sure cache and logs dir are writtable by server... and try a `symfony cc`command to clear the cache.

Comment: They are writable because I see which sql queries are being executed but I'd like to see error messages printed on the screen to make debugging easier.